# Is it possible to set breakpoints in PyGears?

Tags: pygears

As far as I understood I can use any text editor for writing PyGears.
Actually, I need just Python IDE.
Does this mean that I can set breakpoints in any of these tools?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use any Python IDE to develop with PyGears. Breakpoints can also be freely used for debugging.

There are two major phases when a design is simulated with PyGears: compile time and run time.

1. During compile time, the structure of the design is built. Modules are instantiated, parameterized and connected using interfaces. In this phase `non-async` functions are executed, i.e. the functions defined as:

   ```
   @gear
   def func(...):
       ...
   ```

   So placing breakpoints in these functions will help you track, for an example, which exact values are used as module parameters, or to inspect the data types of the interfaces between the modules.
2. Once `sim()` is called, PyGears simulator will execute the design structure by invoking the `async` modules, i.e. the functions defined as:

   ```
   @gear
   async def func(...):
       ...
   ```

   or,

   ```
   @datagear
   def func(...):
       ...
   ```

   Placing breakpoints in these functions lets you debug the functionality of the modules, as well as understand the timing when some of the modules receive input data and produce the outputs.

   However, debugging more complex designs over thousands of clock cycles is usually tedious to perform using breakpoints, so you should also consider using Gearbox (the PyGears IDE), inspecting waveforms, and logging important events.